# Correct meaning of noch nie

Tags: meaning, difference, word-choice, german-to-english, phrase

The website dict.cc translates *noch nie* as "never before". But, *noch* means "yet", thus, *noch nie* should mean "not yet". Which one is the correct meaning of *noch nie*?

Comment: *Nie* is not *not*

Comment: @c.p. Thanks for your comment. But, what about noch which means yet?

Comment: You can't always take expressions apart and expect to combine them like in math.

Comment: Just because a two-word phrase translates to a two-word phrase (dict.cc is correct here) does not imply, that some kind of mapping to  the meaning of the single words can be found.

Comment: @Novice As an addendum to the other comments I agree with: In English, you have *yet* and *not yet* (i.e., by principle: *already/not already*). In German, however, you have *schon* and *noch nicht* (i.e., by principle: *already/still not*). So *not yet* in English is expressed by saying 'it hasn't begun yet to be' (absence of positive state), while in German you'd say 'it's still not being' (presence of negative state).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's *noch nicht* and *noch nie*. In general, you could translate *noch* as *still* (*yet* can also translate to its counterpart *schon* 'already' in some sentences).

***Noch nicht*** literally means *still not* (idiomatically, of course, *not yet*) and suggests *yet to come*.

***Noch nie*** literally means *still never* and is actually translated best as *never before* since it puts the emphasis on the past. It does not imply that it will happen in the future.

NB: *Noch nie* sometimes seems like a stronger version of *nie* (perhaps comparable to *never ever*). This is why you sometimes find it in sentences where in English one would simply use *never* (see example below).

---

Two examples where only one of them would be appropriate:

> Sie hat noch nie etwas gestohlen ('She has never stolen anything [in her whole life]').

*Noch nichts gestohlen* would more or less imply *she's about to steal something*.

> Ich habe seinen Brief noch nicht erhalten. ('I haven't received his letter yet')

You cannot use *noch nie* here because that would mean you *never* received a letter from him. Furthermore, *noch nicht* implies again that the letter is supposed to arrive soon.

Comment: Thanks! Thus, here noch in noch nie means before?

Comment: @Novice I'd translate it as 'up to now' or 'still': *Never up to now*, resp., *still never*.

Comment: @Novice, no, *nie* does not mean *before*, but *noch nie* means *never before*. Just note that different languages are typically not translated word by word but phrase by phrase. For example, the German sentence *Er hat noch nie das Meer gesehen* translated word-by-word would be *He has yet never the sea seen.* The correct translation would be *He hasn't seen the sea before.*

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Thanks for your example and clarification.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Before what?

Comment: @userunknown *Never before* is a fixed phrase (like and meaning *noch nie*)

Answer (score -1):

Mein Englisch ist nur so la la.

*Noch nie* wird bei beiden Gelegenheiten im Deutschen gebraucht, wenn ein Zustand im Moment endet (oder das Ende abzusehen ist):

> Ich habe noch nie ein Beispiel mit Leverkusen gepostet.

oder

> Leverkusen war noch nie Deutscher Meister, aber jetzt, 3 Spieltage vor Saisonende, ist ihnen der Titel nicht mehr streitig zu machen.

Als auch offenlassend, was die Zukunft bringt:

> Ich stehe in Köln auf der Brücke. Donau, Elbe, Rhein - schön, schön. Aber noch nie habe ich das Meer gesehen!

Gäbe es hier als einzigen Kontext Folgendes:

> Sie sah auf die Wellen. Noch nie hatte sie das Meer gesehen.

Dann würde man aber schließen, dass der Zustand jetzt im Moment endet, und sie gerade das Meer sieht.

*Never before* impliziert aber, soweit ich weiß, dass der Zustand jetzt gerade beendet ist oder, wie bei der Meisterschaft, gerade zu Ende geht. Ob *never ever* dann richtig wäre ist hier nicht der Ort zu diskutieren.

Comment: As far as I can see, the question is in English. This makes your answer less helpful, regardless the content.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Yes, but I believe on the German SE is it okay.

Comment: @userunknown Thanks! I will try to understand your answer.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: Dass die Frage auf Englisch gestellt wurde ist meiner Aufmerksamkeit nicht entgangen, aber ich habe großzügig darüber hinweggesehen. Sprachen werden überlicherweise in der Sprache unterrichtet, die gelernt werden soll, um den Lerneffekt zu verdoppeln. Das Thema ist Deutsch, nicht Deutsch für Englischsprachige. Wenn Du eine Verständnisfrage hast, immer raus damit, dafür sind die Kommentare da! Ansonsten bleibt Dir die Möglichkeit die ganze Antwort bei DeepL einzufügen und in eine Deiner bevorzugten 10 Zielsprachen übersetzen zu lassen.

Comment: Ist die Frage wie gut das ankommt, jetzt wo die Frage bei den Hot Questions (Entschuldigung, "heißen Fragen") angezeigt wird. Da werden jetzt viele Leute aus Neugier drauf klicken und diese Antwort nicht verstehen.

Comment: @infinitezero: Du meinst Leute, die kein Deutsch können und kein Deutsch lernen wollen, folgen blindlings der Werbung und wollen dann nur Englisches lesen? Wieso sollte mich das kümmern?

Comment: Weil die Seite für alle da ist und nicht nur für die deiner Selektion. Ich lese auch gerne auf anderen Sprachenseiten mit, weil ich neugierig bin und finde es jedes Mal schade, wenn ich es nicht verstehen kann.

Comment: @infinitezero: Dann ist der DeepL-Tipp vielleicht was für Dich?